# How can I resolve this error? (This type must be an array type but is resolved to a string)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to practice string manipulation skills and I came up with this as a solution to check a string array for every word that ends in 'y' or 'z' (a word being defined as a string of characters separated by a space) but its wrong obviously. What can I do to resolve this error?

```
static int wordEndYZ(String str) 
{

    int i, j, counter;

    for( i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) // search through string array
    {
        j=i;                                // copy position so original position intact
        while ( str[j] == ' ' )             // *First error* space occurs, check last letter
        {
            if ( str[j-1] == 'y' || 'x' )   // 'y' or 'z'? If so counter increments
                counter += 1;               
        }           
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: A `String` is not an array, therefore you cannot use array indexing on it.  Also don't use the term "string array", because you will confuse yourself, unless you actually want an array of `String`s which is totally different.  Look up [`String.charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Comment: Also, if you want to look for `'z'`, it's important to type in the character `'z'` correctly.

Comment: You're asking to find 'Y' or 'Z', but you check for 'Y' and 'X'?

Comment: This would work in C#... do you have a background in C#? I wouldn't think so, as the exception is pretty bloody obvious what it means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings aren't only supposed to be viewed as char arrays. You need to perform the lookup using 
try: String#charAt(int)

Also, study your syntax a little more, I see a few errors that you aren't even referring to. I'm amazed it even compiles. It does compile, right?

Comment: Thank, you. This helps me so much. Looking back now, I am amazed that I even wrote this

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Strings aren't just transparent char arrays. You need to perform the lookup using [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

```
while ( str.charAt(j) == ' ' )
```

Second, there is no syntactic sugar in Java for comparison to multiple values. You must do as follows:

```
if ( str.charAt(j-1) == 'y' || str.charAt(j-1) == 'x' )
```

Comment: Or, if you want to be tricky, you can say `if ("xy".indexOf(str.charAt(j-1)) >= 0)`.

Comment: @ajb Or, one could use numeric comparisons on `char` values, but for someone that is just starting out with Java (or is learning it after learning a low-level language), it would be best to stick with the basics, at least for this case.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I don't think I'd actually use `indexOf` anyway.  I'd probably use a `Set<Character>`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the idea behind my solution is this: split the string into an array, and check every last character in the string array, if it passes the conditions, increment the counter.

```
   static int wordEndYZ(String str) {
        int counter = 0;
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        for(String w : words){
            if(w.charAt(w.length() - 1) == 'y' || w.charAt(w.length() - 1) == 'z'){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```